# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files while Logging in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python file that has some static function. I want to logging this file in the app with below sample code.

Static functions like below;

```
     def sampleFunc:
          LoggerSample().logger.warning("warning message)
```

The class is like below;

```
    class LoggerSample:
        def __init__(self):
            self.logger = logging.getLogger("LoggerSample")
            self.logger.setLevel(Logging.INFO)
            self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
            self.file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.log_path)
            self.file_handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
            self.logger.addHandler(self.file_handler)
        
        def __exit__(self,exc_type,exc_val,exc_tb):
            for handler in self.logger.handlers[:]:
                handler.close()
                self.logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

When I run the code I get below error.

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: [path_to_log_file.log]
```

For solving this error I call removeHandler function in **exit** method, but I still get same error.

**I don't want to change ulimits** I have to solve this issue with coding, not changing the system variables.

How can i solve this ?

Thanks for answering

Comment: Keep in mind that loggers are 'global'. When instantiating `LoggerSample` for the 2nd, 3rd, ... nth time, `logging.getLogger("LoggerSample")` returns an existing logger with handlers attached. On each additional instantiation you add yet another handler representing yet another open FD. Add `print(self.logger.handlers)` to the end of our `__init__` method  to see it happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__exit__` is called only with the `with` construct.

Therefore you do not remove the handlers since the `__exit__` is not called. You should update your code:

```
class LoggerSample:
    def __init__(self,name="LoggerSample"):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self.logger.setLevel(Logging.INFO)
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        self.file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.log_path)
        self.file_handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)    

    def __enter__(self):
        logger = LoggerSample()
        logger.logger.addHandler(self.file_handler)    
        return logger
    
    def __exit__(self,exc_type,exc_val,exc_tb):
        for handler in self.logger.handlers[:]:
            handler.close()
            self.logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

Now you can use the `with` construct when logging. at the end of the `with` construct, `__exit__` will be called and release the resources.

```
with LoggerSample() as ff:
  ff.logger.warning("warning message")
```

Comment: Can you also explain in words why your answer answers the OP’s question, and briefly what the problem was with the OP’s code?

Comment: In `__enter__`, that you call on a instance of `LoggerSample` you create yet another instance of `LoggerSample` to return it. That is unnecessary. Furthermore, you try to call `addHandler` on the new `LoggerSample` instance, which will throw an AttributeError. The line would have to read `logger.logger.addHandler(self.file_handler)`. Still, you could just return `self.logger` in `__enter__`. However, this solution only works around the actual problem that Sven Festersen correctly described in their answer

Comment: Thanks for answering. if put logger = LoggerSample(), I should use logger.logger.addHandler, so should i return logger.logger or the logger object ? Could you modify your code syntax ?

Comment: @shmee, Oh, I missed one logger :-). 
From the question, I assume that creating a new logger is necessary (why to the initialize the same logger each time?)

Comment: The thing is that `logging.getLogger("LoggerSample")` only creates a new logger the first time it is called. On each subsequent call with that name it will return the existing, already configured logger instance as stored in `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict`. Your solution only adds the handler to the existing logger when entering the context and removes it when exiting. That indeed does fix the issue as described by the OP. But creating and removing handlers every time you want to use the logger is not exactly ideal.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that you are configuring the logger each time you use it in one of your functions, including installation of the `FileHandler`. A much better way of using loggers in Python is to configure the logger once at the start of your program and then access it later via `getLogger`, like so:

```
...

def init_logging(log_path):
    logger = logging.getLogger("LoggerSample")
    logger.setLevel(Logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)


def sample_func_a():
    logging.getLogger("LoggerSample").debug("hello from a")

def sample_func_b():
    logging.getLogger("LoggerSample").debug("hello from b")


# run your program
init_logging("/path/to/log_file")
sample_func_a()
sample_func_b()

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function that you can call multiple loggers in the same runtime which can save multiple log files. edit code with your parameters,

```
import os
import logging

if not os.path.exists(r"logs"):
 os.mkdir(r"logs")

def loggerInstance(logger_name, level=logging.DEBUG):
 logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
 logger.setLevel(level)
 format_string = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
 log_format = logging.Formatter(format_string, datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
 # Creating and adding the console handler
 console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
 console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
 logger.addHandler(console_handler)
 # Creating and adding the file handler
 file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logger_name, mode='a')
 file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
 logger.addHandler(file_handler)
 return logger

CRLogger = loggerInstance(f"logs/" + "Log1.log")
CRLogger.info('Log File is Created Successfully')
```

This should work. if you are running in multiple loop or sessions or runtime, this will create a log each time even if it is a sea runtime under the loop. you should save the log file name differently every time in order to that